# How to access an image from tomcat server path

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I simply put an image in Apache Tomcat root directory folder.  For example `C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\abc.jpg`.

Now I want to access that image from browser through HTTP (like `http://localhost:8080/...`).

My Tomcat server in running in Eclipse on 8080 port.  Am I able to access that image through HTTP method? Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

[image: Error Message in Browser]

Comment: You cannot access the Tomcat base directory for security reasons. Try moving the file to the `webapps` subdir.

Comment: if I move that file to webapps folder then what should be my URL to access the image ?@f_puras

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create a `webapps\ROOT` folder if it does not yet exist and move the file in it. It should then be accessible via

```
http://localhost:8080/abc.jpg
```

Comment: Did you restart tomcat?

Comment: So what is your browser's response? 404?

Comment: Yes.Its 404 error.Is there any other way to do this ??

Comment: @GourabSarkar Thanks for updating your question. Looks interesting, when I do it, it works the way described. You made sure the `abc.jpg` is in the `ROOT` folder, which in turn is a subfolder of Tomcat's `webapps`? Like `C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\webapps\ROOT\abc.jpg`?

Comment: yes sir.It is in ROOT folder.I checked it again.What could be done for this problem?Is there any solution ?????

Comment: Ok, I suppose, Eclipse is controlling the Tomcat instance. If so, it redirects the webapps folder to some project\.metadata\.plugins\... If you actually use eclipse for deploying, you need to introduce the picture to your Eclipse project, and move it to the project's webapps folder.

Comment: I am using eclipse for controlling tomcat.My eclipse project is maven based project.

Answer (score 1):

for tomcat 8.0.48, asa you start the server, the images in C:\MercedesJar\apache-tomcat-8.0.48\webapps\ROOT can be accessed using localhost:8080/bg-button.png, for your specific project you can create an images folder in the ROOT and put an index.html (that can be found in examples folder) and images in that folder. http://localhost:8080/images/cars3.JPG (the key here is to put index.html that servers as the landing page.)

Answer (score 0):

- Lookup how to write a DownloadServlet that can serve your files. By making this available to `http://example.com/download/*`, you can serve images as `http://example.com/download/FILENAME.jpg`, for example.
- Choose a sensible different directory - *not* your tomcat directory - to store your files. By doing so you'll separate your more static files (tomcat and webapplications) from dynamic files (content) and ease your backups.
- DO NOT upload files into `tomcat/webapps/ROOT` or `tomcat/webapps/anything` - you'll open yourself up to attacks - e.g. when someone uploads a jsp, they'll be able to execute server-side code.
- Make sure that you're not vulnerable to file system traversal, e.g. by allowing `http://example.com/download/../../../../etc/passwd`